# Magento 1.14. Reindex product_attribute error - PDOException: There is no active transaction in

Tags: php, pdo, magento

Был использован стандартный реиндекс magento. На тестовых серверах с идентичной настройкой базы работает нормально.

```
$ php indexer.php --reindexall
Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog product price index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
URL Redirects index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Category/Product Index index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search Index index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Tag Aggregation Data index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Attributes index process unknown error:
PDOException: There is no active transaction in /var/www/releases/20170105071630Z/public/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:322
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/releases/20170105071630Z/public/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(322): PDO->rollBack()
#1 /var/www/releases/20170105071630Z/public/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(524): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_rollBack()
#2 /var/www/releases/20170105071630Z/public/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(266): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->rollBack()
#3 /var/www/releases/20170105071630Z/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(124): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->rollback()
#4 /var/www/releases/20170105071630Z/public/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Abstract.php(57): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract->rollBack()
#5 /var/www/releases/20170105071630Z/public/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav.php(185): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Abstract->reindexAll()
#6 /var/www/releases/20170105071630Z/public/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav->reindexAll()
#7 /var/www/releases/20170105071630Z/public/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#8 /var/www/releases/20170105071630Z/public/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#9 /var/www/releases/20170105071630Z/public/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#10 /var/www/releases/20170105071630Z/public/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#11 {main}
```

Код: public\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Indexer\Eav\Abstract.php

```
    public function reindexAll()
    {
        $this->useIdxTable(true);
        $this->beginTransaction();

        try {
            $this->clearTemporaryIndexTable();
            $this->_prepareIndex();
            $this->_prepareRelationIndex();
            $this->_removeNotVisibleEntityFromIndex();

            $this->syncData();
            $this->commit();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die(var_dump($e->errorInfo));
            $this->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привет, та же проблема на Magento CE 1.9.3 - помогло отключение постоянных соединений в local.xml, которые далее в адаптере передаются в объект PDO  `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true` при инициализации

Не знаю почему, но включение/отключение в php.ini не помогало, но сразу после удаления `<persistent>1</persistent>` из секции `connection` в local.xml все начало работать как надо (надо сбросить кеш конфигурации после данного изменения)

Так-же тут может играть роль версия php или самого модуля pdo, у нас все работало с этим конфигом до обновления.

Поломалось вот на этой версии:

`[root@web ~]# php -v
PHP 7.0.16 (cli) (built: Feb 14 2017 17:22:12) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.16, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies`

Comment: Благодарю, помогло.